# Facebook Connect Vs Facebook registration

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-social-plugins

What's the difference between Facebook Connect and Facebook Registration?
And How can I get user's ID with facebook connect?

Answer (score 2):

The Registration Plugin offers two key features not available with the Login Button: support for users without Facebook accounts and the ability to request additional user information that Facebook may not have or make available.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook Registration help the user in registering to your website by using their Facebook Data to fill in the reg for for your website. Facebook connect is used to log the user into your website so they don't need to register for a separate account.